# 'find' img tag and apply click event to it

Tags: jquery, image

i have been having an issue where i need to apply a click event to a dynamically created img tag,

(When a user uploads a file, an image X is added to the page in an anchor tag to allow the user a friendly way to remove the file from being uploaded)

I have this:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DocumentUpload1_file_upload2_wrap_list').find('img').click(function()
{
    alert("teststs");
});
```

This i hoped would find any img element as a child or grandchild of the element with the ID `#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DocumentUpload1_file_upload2_wrap_list` and apply the click event to it, but no alert comes up,

Many thanks in advance

EDIT: here is the html i am trying to traverse to get to the img tag

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DocumentUpload1_file_upload2_wrap_list" class="MultiFile-list"> 
<div class="MultiFile-label"> 
<a class="MultiFile-remove" href="#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DocumentUpload1_file_upload2_wrap"> 
<img width="12px" src="App_Theme/Images/CloseImage.jpg">
```

Comment: Have you considered using the .on() functionality?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, i did try this first - i have edited my original post to include the html tree i am traversing to apply the click event to the img tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), since this is a much better approach. You can bind the event once in your DOMRead function, and it will be applied to all images that are inserted:

```
$(function() {  
    $(document).on('click', '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DocumentUpload1_file_upload2_wrap_list img', function() {  
        alert("teststs");
    });
});
```

Not here that we pass a selector as the second argument to event binding. From the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> **selector**
>  Type: String
>  A selector string to filter the descendants of
>   the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null
>   or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected
>   element.

You should of course note that this requires jQuery >= 1.7.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying so quickly - i did try this (i did actually try '.on' first but to no avail - perhaps something else i am doing is wrong - i edited my original post with some more information

Comment: It seems that having an href on the img is affecting the functionality, when i remove the href, then the alert goes off fine?

But i need the href for its own functionality lol, catch 22 ill try build the href functionality into your .on function.

Thank you for the help - as your answer was essentially correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try event delegation: using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), Since you are dealing with the dynamically generated elements:

```
$(function() {  
    $(document).on('click', '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DocumentUpload1_file_upload2_wrap_list img', function() {  
        alert("teststs");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please

```
$(function() {  
    $(document).on('click', '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DocumentUpload1_file_upload2_wrap_list img', function() {  
        alert("teststs");
    });
});
```